# Permission denied for read pickle-file under scheduler and bash script

Tags: python-3.x, bash, cron, pickle, root

I have an executable bash script (`.sh`) which should be run 2 python scripts consistently (only when first is successfully finished then the second one will be started), `run_script.sh` has the following view:

```
#!/bin/bash
#!/usr/bin/python3
scripts='/path/to/file/file1.py /path/to/file/file2.py'
for s in $scripts
do
    echo $s
    /usr/bin/python3 $s
done
```

As a scheduler I use `crontab job`:

```
26 14 10-23 * * cd /path/to/file/ && /path/to/file/run_script.sh >> /home/log/crontab_LOG.log 2>&1
```

In process of data aggregation in python scripts I use `.pickle` files.
But, in result of execution the suggested python scripts (`file1.py` and `file2.py`)  by `.sh` file, I received and error:

```
PermissionError [Errno 13 ] Permission denied: '/path/to/file/example.pickle'
```

btw: `example.pickle` file is created in process of execute `file1.py`,not out of run where it used.

When try to execute  `sh run_script.sh` by terminal without any scheduler, there is no any error to permissions. So, result is success.

I also try to search my question, but it was not success. ([Permission denied for Python script using Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38355791/how-to-give-executable-permission-to-all-python-scripts-in-linux)), [IO Error while storing data in pickle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285181/io-error-while-storing-data-in-pickle)

The question is how I can set the the root permission by bash script to required python scripts?

Comment: The problem is not the execute permission of the bash script. the problem is that your python script is running as a user that does not have write permission to `path/to/file/example.pickle`. Perhaps that is because `path/to/file/example.pickle` is missing the `/` character at the beginning?

Comment: is your `run_script.sh` and `file1.py` are in the same directory well as `.pickle` file. Basically check if all these scripts have the proper flow of directories. Also, check if `cron` user have permission for these scripts if not running from `root`

Comment: @AvinashYadav, now  `run_script.sh` and  `file1.py` are in the same directory, but the path for saved by `file1.py` script example.pickle file is in subdirectory  of folder where `file1.py` located. I'll try to move it to one directory. Yes, cron user has permission to run scripts. Thanks for idea.

Comment: @AndrewVickers, it has '/' at the beginning, it was just my typos in question. Thanks

Comment: @Cindy Did you tried moving in the same directory

Comment: @AvinashYadav, yes I moved it to the same directory and modified the `crontab job` to the following view: 

`30 14 10-23 * * cd /home/path/to/file/ && /usr/bin/python3 file1.py && /usr/bin/python3 file2.py >> /home/logs/crontab_LOG.log 2>&1`. Now It works, but I need to find solution how to move results file (`.pickle`) from main directory (where `file1.py` and `file2.py` are located). I tried to move it to subdirectory, but an error about `Permission denied` happens again.

Comment: @Cindy Good to know that it worked, I can help is you share your file1.py snippet where it try to access .pickle file.

Comment: @AvinashYadav, there is a function in `file1.py`:  `def readPickleData(key, path, file='example.pickle'):     data = pickle.load(open(path + file, 'rb'))     print(data.keys())     data = data[key]    return data`.So, in process of run `file1.py` I save `df` to `example.pickle` then use it for next aggregation. Code for saving `df` to `pickle` is here:`pc.dump({'data': df, },  open(path+'example.pickle`. It would be great to move `example.pickle` from main directory (where `file1.py` located: `main_code`) to subdirectory (`/main_code/files`) with permissions to it. How it could be achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was fixed by usage approach with `Path`:

```
from pathlib import Path
example_pickle = Path('logs/example_pickle'+datetime.now()+'.pickle')
```

Thanks everyone for the inspired ideas:)